# How to passing value to textbox in second form when object has been launched

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, show

I make project in winforms with the C#.

I have two forms. Opening with the Show() and midiContainer.

Example:

I open Form1, where I have eg. TextBox with data about Customer (Name company).  I selected Customer from second Form2. I secleded value from grid. I have this data. I Can't passing value to first Form1.

I thinking first Form1 is initiated the first. How passing value to first form from second form?

I tryed use reflection. Unfortunately, doesn't solve problem.

This problem doesn't occur when use ShowDialog().

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass `Form1` into the constructor of your `Form2`. A simple practical example:

```
// On Form 1
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var frm = new Form2(this); // bein
    frm.Show();
}

public void GetValue(string Text)
{
    // Do something
}

// On Form2
private Form1 Form;
public Form2(Form1 form)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.Form1 = form;
   this.Form1.GetValue("Hi");
}
```